# powershell transaction office 365

Tags: powershell, transactions, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to create a user, contact and a distribution list in office 365 using Powershell.

I need to set a transaction to be sure that I execute successfully all the three commands or nothing.

My commands are :

```
New-MsolUser -DisplayName 'TEST TEST' -FirstName 'TEST' -LastName 'TEST' -UserPrincipalName 'TEST.TEST@TEST.onmicrosoft.com' -UsageLocation US

New-MailContact -Name 'TEST TEST' -ExternalEmailAddress 'TEST@gmail.com'

New-DistributionGroup -Name 'TEST TEST_TEST' -Members 'TEST@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Each command does separate things, so they are executed one by one and has no relationship between them. If you want to have all or nothing, you need to add some kind of check to this script that if at least one command failed - delete already created resources.

For example if `New-MsolUser` succeeds and `New-MailContact` fails. you need to run "cleanup" part which would execute `Remove-MsolUser`.

For making it easier you should define all the information to variables like:

```
$username = test@blabla.onmicrosoft.com, $ext_email_address
```

and so on. I think you got the point. :)